# Plugin uninstalled but view still in menu

Tags: eclipse

I have some trouble after installed plugin that I am developing in the same IDE. It probably did some fails after I started the eclipse from `Manifest.MF` (that for testing purposes). Now even if I uninstalled that plugin, I still see view from that plugin in "Show view" menu and after click, it tells that this view cannot be created.

I tried all of the below, none of which worked:

- run Eclipse with `-clean` flag
- remove `artifacts.xml` in Eclipse root directory
- uninstall normal way
- revert in installation history
- install and uninstall my plugin again

I tried to install that plugin in other Eclipse and everything was fine.
That bug happened definitely because I installed it to same IDE where I develop it and then turned on that Eclipse for plugin test purpose (via `MANIFEST.MF`).

It looks that I will need to reinstall Eclipse or there is any other way how to remove everything of any plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to know what's going exactly but here are some things you can try:

1. Make sure that your plugin doesn't exist in the eclipse/plugins directory. And that there is no feature in the eclipse/features directory.
2. Open your eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info file outside of eclipse and when eclipse is closed. Look for the line for your plugin and delete it.
3. Reinstall Eclipse.  But, before you do so, export your preferences and reimport them so you don't have to re-set everything again.

The first two are definitely hacks, and are really only used when you have hosed your installation and don't want to reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is to remove .metadata directory in workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the .metadata directory in workspace is not recommended because all of your settings will be lost.

Right-click on the view of the plugin that does not exist anymore and select `Close`